# Reorder the rows of a specific column in CSV

Tags: python, csv

From a csv file, I'm trying to put in an ascending order the different rows of a big column (named CRIM) to do other manipulations after. First, I tried this:

```
def house_data():
  with open('data.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    data = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for line in data:
      print(sorted(line['CRIM']))
```

But then it gave me a result of ordering every numbers in the values and not the value between them.

For example, if I had the number 1.96 and 0.92 , they would give me an output like this:

```
['1', '.','6', '9']
['0','.','2','9']
```

but I wanted

```
['0.92']
['1.96']
```

I read something about using the `lambda` and I tried this, but I didn't get any output.

```
def house_data():
  with open('data.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    data = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    sorted(data, key=lambda line: line['CRIM'])
    for line in data:
      print(line['CRIM'])
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "rows of a column"? To change the file, you're going to need to rewrite the whole thing incorporating whatever changes you desire.

Comment: Open your CSV file by numpy.loadtxt and then sort it by numpy.sort.

Comment: I have more than hundred datas in the column 'CRIM' that I want to order. It's an extern file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use pandas

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
file_path = Path('data.csv') 
dataframe =  pd.read_csv(file_path) # pass other required parameters.
dataframe.sort_values(['CRIM'])
```

Answer (score 0):

First load all the data into a list and then sort the list using 'CRIM' as the key:

```py
def house_data():
    with open('data.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
        data = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        lines = []  # all the lines
        for line in data:
            lines.append(line)
        # or skip the for loop and do:
        # lines = list(data)
    
    # lines is a list of dictionaries
    # now sort `lines` in-place using 'CRIM' as a float
    lines.sort(key=lambda d: float(d['CRIM']))
    return lines
```